# Can receive but cant send data to firebase, Code problem?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

While i'm trying to send those values into the Firebase i'm getting this error: "Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but printers has 1"
ill post pictures of the code below maybe someone can shed some light on this thanks a lot!

```js
Typescript:

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PrintersService } from '../printers.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-addprinter',
  templateUrl: './addprinter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addprinter.component.css']
})
export class AddprinterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private printersService: PrintersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  AddPrinter(form) {

    this.printersService.AddPrinter(
      form.value.hostName,
      form.value.ip,
       form.value.location,
        form.value.manufacturer,
         form.value.model,
          form.value.specificLocation).then(
    data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    console.log(form);
  }
}
```

```css
Service:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PrintersService {

  constructor(private fs: AngularFirestore) { }

  getAllPrinters() {
    return this.fs.collection('Printers').valueChanges();
  }

  AddPrinter(HostName, Ip, Location, Manufacturer, Model, SpecificLocation) {
    return this.fs.doc('Printers/').set({
      HostName,
      Ip,
      Location,
      Manufacturer,
      Model,
      SpecificLocation

    });

  }
}
```

```html
HTML:

<br><br><br><br>
<h2 class="text-center">Add Printer</h2>

<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="AddPrinter(f)">

<input ngModel name="hostName" #hostname="ngModel" type="text" class="formControl" required placeholder="Enter HostName here">
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="hostname.touched &&hostname.errors?.required">The HostName is requied</div>


<input ngModel name="ip" #ip="ngModel" type="text" class="formControl" required placeholder="Enter Ip here">
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="ip.touched &&ip.errors?.required">The Ip is requied</div>


<input ngModel name="location" #location="ngModel" type="text" class="formControl" required placeholder="Enter Loctaion here">
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="location.touched &&location.errors?.required">The Location is requied</div>


<input ngModel name="manufacturer" #manufacturer="ngModel" type="text" class="formControl" required placeholder="Enter Manufacturer here">
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="manufacturer.touched &&manufacturer.errors?.required">The Manufacturer is requied</div>


<input ngModel name="Model" #model="ngModel" type="text" class="formControl" required required placeholder="Enter Model here">
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="model.touched &&model.errors?.required">The Model is requied</div>


<input ngModel name="specificLocation" #specificLocation="ngModel" type="text" class="formControl" required placeholder="Enter Specific Location here">
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="specificLocation.touched && specificLocation.errors?.required">The Specific Location is requied</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="f.invalid">Send</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is complaining about this line:

```
this.fs.doc('Printers/').set({ ... })
```

If you want to create a document with `set()`, you must provide the full path including the collection where it lives, for example "Printers/printer_id".

If you are trying to add a new document with a random ID, use `add()` instead of `set()`.

```
this.fs.collection('Printers').add({ ... })
```

Comment: but the id is set automatically... how shell i do it?

Comment: Add it to the path of the document that you pass to doc() as I illustrated in the answer.